# Opening form tag unrecognized

Tags: html, webmatrix, iis-express, asp.net-webpages

[image]I am using webmatrix 3 to create ASP.NET web-pages, and one of these pages have a form opening and closing tags, but whenever I launch this page, I get a server error in the browser telling me that the closing `</form>` tag has no opening tag, but I double checked and the IDE (webmatrix 3) displayed no errors. I am sure I missed something but here is the code. note: this is not the whole file its just the html `<form>` part.

```
<form method="post" action="">
        <fieldset style="margin-right: 210px">
            <legend><strong>Fill in the form to register an employee.</strong></legend>
                <table style=" border: 0px;">
                    <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: right; border: 0px;"></td>
                    <td style="border: 0px;"></td>
                  </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: right; border: 0px;"><label for="employee_ssn">Employee's SSN: </label></td>
                    <td style="border: 0px;"><input type="text" size="50px" name="employee_ssn" value=""></td>
                  </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: right; border: 0px;"><label for="first_name">First Name: </label></td>
                    <td style="border: 0px;"><input type="text" size="50px" name="first_name" value=""></td>
                  </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: right; border: 0px;"><label for="middle_name">Middle Name: </label></td>
                    <td style="border: 0px;"><input type="text" size="50px" name="middle_name" value=""></td>
                  </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: right; border: 0px;"><label for="last_name">Last Name: </label></td>
                    <td style="border: 0px;"><input type="text" size="50px" name="last_name" value=""></td>
                  </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: right; border: 0px;"><label for="dob">Date Of Birth: </label></td>
                    <td style="border: 0px;"><input type="date" size="50px" name="dob" value=""></td>
                  </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: right; border: 0px;"><label for="gender">Gender: </label></td>
                    <td style="border: 0px;"><input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">Male<br>
                                             <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female</td>
                  </tr>

                    <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: right; border: 0px;"><label for="blood_type">Blood Type: </label></td>
                    <td style="border: 0px;"><select name="blood_type">
                        <option value="AB+">AB+</option>
                        <option value="AB-">AB-</option>
                        <option value="A+">A+</option>
                        <option value="A-">A-</option>
                        <option value="B+">B+</option>
                        <option value="B-">B-</option>
                        <option value="O">O</option>
                    </select></td>
                  </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: right; border: 0px;"><label for="phone">Telephone Number: </label></td>
                    <td style="border: 0px;"><input type="text" size="50px" name="phone" value=""></td>
                  </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: right; border: 0px;"><label for="mobile">Mobile Number: </label></td>
                    <td style="border: 0px;"><input type="text" size="50px" name="mobile" value=""></td>
                  </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: right; border: 0px;"><label for="address">Address: </label></td>
                    <td style="border: 0px;"><input type="text" size="50px" name="address" value=""></td>
                  </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: right; border: 0px;"><label for="email">e-mail Address: </label></td>
                    <td style="border: 0px;"><input type="text" size="50px" name="email" value=""></td>
                  </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: right; border: 0px;"><label for="job">Occupation: </label></td>
                    <td style="border: 0px;"><input type="text" size="50px" name="job" value=""></td>
                  </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: right; border: 0px;"><label for="spec_degree">Specialization Degree: </label></td>
                    <td style="border: 0px;"><input type="text" size="50px" name="spec_degree" value=""></td>
                  </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: right; border: 0px;"><label for="depatment">Department: </label></td>
                    <td style="border: 0px;"><input type="text" size="50px" name="depatment" value=""></td>
                  </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: right; border: 0px;"><label for="nationality">Nationality: </label></td>
                    <td style="border: 0px;"><input type="text" size="50px" name="nationality" value=""></td>
                  </tr>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: right; border: 0px;"><label for="working_hours">Working Hours: </label></td>
                    <td style="border: 0px;"><input type="text" size="50px" name="working_hours" value=""></td>
                  </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: right; border: 0px;"><label for="emergency_contact">Emergency Contact: </label></td>
                    <td style="border: 0px;"><input type="text" size="50px" name="emergency_contact" value=""></td>
                  </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: right; border: 0px;"><label for="pwd">Password: </label></td>
                    <td style="border: 0px;"><input type="password" size="50px" name="pwd" value=""></td>
                  </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: right; border: 0px;"><label for="confirm_pwd">Confirm Password: </label></td>
                    <td style="border: 0px;"><input type="password" size="50px" name="confirm_pwd" value=""></td>
                  </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: right; border: 0px;"><label for="notes">Notes: </label></td>
                    <td style="border: 0px;"><textarea name="notes"></textarea></td>
                  </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td style="border: 0px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="submit" value=" Register"/></td>
                    </tr>

                </table>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Comment: Try checking ALL the tags and make sure they are all properly balanced. Just because it "thinks" the `</form>` tag had no matching start tag, doesn't really mean that it isn't confused about this as a result of other unbalanced tags.

Comment: I wonder if the '<input>' tags need to be closed

Comment: James is right. Instead of `<input type="password" size="50px" name="pwd" value="">` as an input tag, you should properly close them like this `<input type="password" size="50px" name="pwd" value="" />` That having been said, I made a form element with nested input tags that didn't close, like yours, and I was not able to recreate this error, so my guess is that this isn't the reason for your error, however, you should definitely close these input tags properly, anyway. Also, make sure you're checking any applicable layouts, razor-generated html, etc.

Comment: You may benefit from "viewing page source" after the page is actually loaded, just to see if any tags are off, imbalanced, etc.

Comment: I also noticed that you have two closing `</tr>` tags one after the other on one of those lines, and I don't think that's applicable given your html structure. You may want to check that out, because that could confuse the parser.